# Vaadin fail to load Failed to load the widgetset

Tags: java, maven, plugins, websphere, vaadin

I have changed from vaadin 7.7.12 to 7.7.24, on IBM websphere 8.5; I've compiled the widgetset with vaadin plugin 7.7.24; I install the ear on IBM Was;
The compilation give me no problem and I can istall the ear correctely on IBM WAS;
But when I try to load the page a pop up tell me:

```
Failed to load the widgetset: /wps/TEM_COMP_STACO/themes/TEM_COMP/VAADIN/widgetsets/AppWidgetset/AppWidgetset.nocache.js?1642423338694
```

I've checked that on the server side there is a file called AppWidgetset.nocache.js, but for some reason it cannot be loaded on the page;

Trying more than on time, and the number at the end change 1642423338694, I cannot figure out what that number means;

I cannot change to any vaadin version greater than 7.x.x;
I cannot figure out where is the issue.
any help is appreciated.
Francesco

Comment: The number is just a cache-breaker. Check your build process to make sure that the compilation of the widget set results in the missing artifactrs.  Then make sure, the file is contained in your WAR. If that all seems fine, compare the locations of the file with your previous build.

Comment: I just changed the plugin and vaadin version from 7.7.12 to 7.7.24; nothing else;

Comment: Do you have the extended maintenance subscription? If you don't, the license check will fail for any version above 7.7.17 https://vaadin.com/support/vaadin-7-extended-maintenance . If you do have the subscription, check whether there are any errors when you build the widgetset. You can get more details if you set `<style>DETAILED</style>` in your gwt-maven-plugin's `<configuration>` section in your pom.xml.

Comment: Note that the widgetset build can pass even if there are errors, check the entire log, not just the end results.

Comment: @Anna Koskinen thanks for your help;  I've changed from <style>OBF</style> to <style>DETAILED</style>; But see anything that seems an error in all log, there are warning:  [WARNING] Vaadin plugin could not find any themes [WARNING] GWT plugin is configured to detect modules, but none were found.

Comment: there is a widgetset compilation: [INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.7.24:compile (default) @ WIDGETSETPORTLET ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [AppWidgetset]
[INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 7.7.24
[INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 7.7.24
[INFO] Compiling module AppWidgetset
[INFO]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.vaadin.client.metadata.ConnectorBundleLoader'
[INFO]       Rebinding com.vaadin.client.metadata.ConnectorBundleLoader

Comment: And it all works as expected if you do the same things with 7.7.12 ? Is that 'could not find any themes' warning present there?

Comment: I do not know how, I've just recompiled and the pop up disappear

Comment: Could you write that in answer so that it is clearly visible for the others that case is closed. It is part of code of conduct in SO.

Answer (score -1):

I've recompiled again and also I correct a mistake (I've copied the folder AppWidgetset in two path, deleted the wrong one and the message disapppered;